# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) only thrown on a single view when I have disabled CSRF protections on POST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am developing a django backend using the djangorestframework and simplejwt authentication. I am using it for a react native mobile app so I am disabling CSRF protections for my views. For some reason, even though every other view works without issue, my token blacklist view throws an error `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)` For example the following view works fine:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class BusinessProfileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, HasAccountOwnershipBP)
    
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = BusinessProfileSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            ...
    
    def put(self, request, format='json'):
        ...
```

But this token blacklist view throws the above error

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch') 
class BlackListToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        refresh = request.data['refresh']
        try:
            #get this refresh token from outstanding and invalidate it
            token = RefreshToken(refresh)
            token.blacklist()

            print('ran')
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I've tried setting csrf exempt on the post method directly but that doesn't seem to help anything. I initially tried to use simplejwt's packaged token blacklist but that also threw the same error so I was trying to gain some more control over the view creation with this custom version.

Just in case here is my middleware list as I'm aware the order can affect things

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```

Can someone please help me solve this? I'm confused as to why this particular view fails when other generic and nongeneric views function perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue was to do with how I was calling this view in the front end. I found out by turning off the CSRF View Middleware and then redoing the request at which point I received a 404, it turned out I was missing the trailing slash from the URL (`url/api` vs `url/api/`) and this caused the URLconf to not recognize the request.

This throws the CSRF cookie error before throwing a 404 because the CSRF middleware just sees this as a view that we haven't created a csrf exemption for.